# Bootstrap side tabbed pane

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

Hi all I am trying to get an iframe of 500x200 to be on the right side of the tabs.
If the amount of tabs is more than the 200 height then id like to be able to have them be scrollable. Could someone point me in the right direction?
I'l eventually put the iframe in a panel and have the panel the size of col-lg-9 to fill the rest of the space.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#dpa" data-toggle="tab">DPA</a></li>
              <li><a href="#rn" data-toggle="tab">Antwon</a></li>
              <li><a href="#sss" data-toggle="tab">SSS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ad" data-toggle="tab">Ad</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                  <p>test</p>            
                </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="dpa" data-src="http://www.google.ie">
                  <iframe src="" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
                </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="rn" data-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/37138051?badge=0">
                  <iframe src="" width="500" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/37138051">ANTWON ♦ HELICOPTER</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/tauszik">Brandon Tauszik</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="sss" data-src="http://www.reddit.com/">
                  <iframe src="" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
                </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="ad" data-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/37138051?badge=0">
                  <iframe src="" width="500" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/37138051">ANTWON ♦ HELICOPTER</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/tauszik">Brandon Tauszik</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#myTabs').bind('show', function(e) {  
    paneID = $(e.target).attr('href');
    src = $(paneID).attr('data-src');
    // if the iframe hasn't already been loaded once
    if($(paneID+" iframe").attr("src")=="")
    {
        $(paneID+" iframe").attr("src",src);
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, something like this?

```
#myTabs {float:left; height:200px; overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: the iframes still appear below the tabs